# Need help writng grammars for a C++ comment

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I am learning about regular grammars in a class I'm currently taking. I need to make a regular grammar that will recognize a comment in a C++ or Java program. The comment starts with /* and ends with */ and anything else in between can be ignored. I am not considering the case of nested comments. I can have any number of * characters at the beginning, at the end, and in between. I'm unsure of how to handle strokes in the middle. What I have done so far is below I'm not sure if what I have is the right idea. Thanks.

```
S => /A
A=> *B
B=> *B
B=> digitB
B=> letterB
B=> symbolB
B=> *C
C=> /D
D=> end
```

Comment: Are you targetting 'a C++ comment' or rather 'a comment in a C++ code'? For example, a sequence of characters like this `/*" "*/` is a valid comment, but as a part of `"/*" "*/"` it's not (the latter sequence is a string literal defining a 4-characters string containing `'/'`, `'*'`, another `'*'`, `'/'` and a terminating NUL character `'\0'`).

Comment: BTW, how about tail comments, starting with a doubled slash...?

Comment: The rule `B=> symbolB` seems too weak. A single asterisk is allowed inside a C++ comment, as well as a single slash. And a sequence of asterisks or a sequence of slashes is OK, too. So for this rule to work your `symbol` class needs to contain both `*` and `/`. However, this would allow for a sequence of two symbols `*/` _inside_ a comment (for example like `/* from here */ till there */`. This is against the definition, which says the pair `*/` terminates the comment.

Comment: Is there a way of writing to exclude certain characters ? We are targeting a comment in C++ code so it will recognize it as a comment when it sees /* and end at */. I'm confused on how to go about targeting the characters inside of comments. The tail comments we are ignoring for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Your description is incorrect:

> The comment starts with /* and ends with */ and anything else in between can be ignored.

It should be:

> The comment starts with /* and ends with */ with anything in between except */.

So—as you said—an asterisk can appear, and multiple times, inside a comment.

This implies scanning and testing a single character is not enough to tell if you're still in the comment's body, because an asterisk may well be a comment's internal character *OR* a terminator's part.

For example, in /****/

- the first asterisk fits the rule `A=> *B`,
- the second and the third one fit `B=> *B`,
- but the fourth one could be matched either with `B=> *B` or `B=> *C`,

and you'll not know which one is correct unless you take `B=> *C` and then test and fail `C=> /D`. And if it fails you need to backtrack and assume it was `B=> *B`.
However, if you take `B=> *B` as the first guess, you may accept the */ sequence as the comment's content instead of a comment's terminator.

I suppose you need to distinguish two states corresponding to the comment's content: one which follows an asterisk and one which follows anything else.

Let B denote the general comment content and Q a content following an asterisk. Then:

```
S=> / A
A=> * B
B=> [anything-except-asterisk] B
B=> * Q
Q=> [anything-except-slash] B
B=> * C
C=> / D
D=> end
```

might do, I think.

Of course there is still an ambiguity between `B=> * Q` and `B=> * C`, but with this definition each choice is confirmed or discarded by a next input character.
At least you know you won't misinterpret a */ pair and let it by as a comment's content.

Comment: A regular grammar does not need to be deterministic or even unambiguous.